# Ionic / Cordova installation failure

Tags: windows, cordova, ionic-framework

Can you help me to resolve the problem with Ionic and Cordova shown in the screenshot below?

[image]

Comment: Please post actual error messages instead of screenshots. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to latest npm and run as non-admin (if you were) and give it a try again.

```
npm install -g npm
```

or first try updating packages

```
npm update -g
```

Answer (score 0):

Update npm to latest version and check again.

```
npm install -g npm
```

If problem persists then update the node also.

Then you are good to go.